# How to Count all with condition Date Now

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, codeigniter-3

I try to count all my row with date condition in my web, but I don't know why my code still didn't work. I try add (date) in front my column(created_at) but the result:

> error "Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean"

This is my code:

```
    public function hitungPerbaikan()
    {
        $date = new DateTime('now');
        $curr_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $this->db->where('update_at', $curr_date);
        $this->db->where('status >=', '2'); 
        $this->db->from('tbl_kerusakan');
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
```

Comment: Seems like the query is generating an error on SQL Server so the result in PHP is `false` instead of a dataset, which is what causes `count_all_results()` to fail. You'd be better off invoking `$db_result = $this->db->get()`, testing if `$db_result` is `false` (a failure) and then returning `$db_result->num_rows()` when it is not an error.

Comment: If I were to guess at the cause of the error most likely `update_at` is a `datetime` column and your connection/server has `set dateformat dmy` in effect. Try using `$date->format('Ymd')` instead to see if the error goes away. This would generate `20211227` for today, instead of `2021-12-27`, and will successfully cast to a `datetime` value when `set dateformat dmy` is in effect.

Comment: thanks that help a lot, i know now about datetime format sqlserver,  in the end of the day im add >=  in my where to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank for the advice, its really help me to figure it out, this is my code now

```
public function hitungPerbaikan()
{
    $date = new DateTime('now');
    $curr_date = $date->format('ymd');
    $this->db->where('update_at>=', $curr_date);
    $this->db->where('status >=', '2');
    $this->db->from('tbl_kerusakan');
    $db_result = $this->db->get();
    return $db_result->num_rows();
}
```